# SharePoint Online - Some fields are not loaded in List Item CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, caml-query, linq

1) I am getting list items from a list by CAML query in ListItemCollection objects of Max 5000 items

2) I am pushing each ListItemCollection into a List of ListItem to enable the capability of querying via LINQ. I am using ListItemCollection position to continue from the next 5000 list items.

3) I want to do some querying by 2 specific fields in 2 different scenarios. Both fields are Lookup fields looking into 2 different libraries.

One of them is working, the other is not. I get:

```
The given key was not present in this dictionary
```

I tried replicating the non-working column with another one created from scratch. I still got the same error.

I noticed that when traversing the List by a ForEach, if I do not load each ListItem by context.Load, I do not see all the fields within the ListItem. Case in point, if I do not do:

```
ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

I can extract:

```
item.FieldValues["Column1"]
```

but not:

```
item.FieldValues["Column2"]
```

or:

```
item.FieldValues["Column3"]
```

I need to be able to load all the FieldValues of all the items either at 1) or 2). For sure, this cannot be done by a Foreach as it would take ages and will defeat the purpose of using CAML Query and LINQ.

Comment: try just `item["Column1"]` and `item["Column2"]`

Comment: I tried it at the moment of populating the List<ListItem> items. items[0]["Column1"] loads but not Column2. Also in LINQ, I don't think you can do: 
c => c["Column1"] != null but rather c=> c.FieldValues["Column1"] != null (for e.g.)

Comment: What ViewFields are you requesting with your CAML query? Be sure you're specifying both fields.

Comment: This is how I am assigning the CAML Query. I am not specifying any fields -
 Should it be done in another way?: camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>5000</RowLimit></View>";